# Using Lua in listed elements (List of Figures, List of Tables, List of Content)

Tags: sectioning, luatex, automation, lua

I am not sure if I use the wrong approach or if this is an issue in LuaLaTex in general. I tried to integrate some internationalization (I18n) to our documentation framework using Lua. Long story, short: I want to read the caption of general sections like 'references', 'appendix' and other from a resource file. But using a luaexec in \chapter or \section writes useless entries to .aux and therefore also in .toc .lof and .lot files.

This is my small sample:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{luacode}

\newcommand{\intString}[1]{\luaexec{tex.print("#1")}}

\begin{document}
\section{\intString{test}} %this breaks
\intString{lofCaption}  % this works

\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\intString{lofCaption}} % this breaks
\protect\listoffigures

\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\intString{lotCaption}} % this breaks
\protect\listoftables
\end{document}
```

I have no idea why this causes some entries like this in my .aux file:

```
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}\begingroup \escapechar 92 \newlinechar 10 \edef \\{\\}\edef \nobreakspace  {}{~}\let \%=%\let \#=#\endgroup test}{1}}
```

It looks like during creation of .aux file the lua code is neither executed nor written to the .aux but replaced by something looking like a reference.

Does anyone know if this is a malfunction of LuaLaTeX or if there is a mistake on my part?

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It mostly depends on what you want to write in the `.toc` file. With `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{<tokens>}` you write in the `.toc` file a line `\contentsline{chapter}{<expansion of tokens>}` and that' in fact the expansion of `\luaexec`

Comment: Hi Egreg,
thanks for this clarification, the \contentsline works perfect, but while using \section it still crashes. Is there any way to force expansion?

Comment: Are there any news here? Lua seems a bit complicated for that stuff, you could as well use the `babel` mechanism for that.

Answer (score 3):

The `luacode` commands are not expandable or robust, so need `\protect`. But `\protect` needs to be applied in the moving argument, using it at the top level like

```
\protect\listoftables
```

does nothing as `\protect` is `\relax` at that point.

So this works

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{luacode}

\newcommand{\intString}[1]{\luaexec{tex.print("#1")}}

\begin{document}
\section{\protect\intString{test}} %this breaks
\intString{lofCaption}  % this works

\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\intString{lofCaption}} % this breaks
\listoffigures

\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\intString{lotCaption}} % this breaks
\listoftables
\end{document}
```

or more simply you can use `\directlua` not the `luacode` package wrapper as that is expandable.

So this also works

```
\documentclass[]{article}


\newcommand{\intString}[1]{\directlua{tex.print("#1")}}

\begin{document}
\section{\intString{test}} %this breaks
\intString{lofCaption}  % this works

\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\intString{lofCaption}} % this breaks
\listoffigures

\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\intString{lotCaption}} % this breaks
\listoftables
\end{document}
```

the two verions are not equivalent, in the second version `intString` is expanded as the `aux` file is written out, in the first version `\intString` is written as `\intString` to the `aux` file and expanded when that file is read back in. The end result is the same in this example.